# No partitions found when installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, format

I am trying to install windows 7 on my HDD, it boots and everything, but when it comes to selecting a partition to install on I cant find any.

Comment: Perhaps your PC requires SATA/AHCI/RAID drivers. Check manufacturer's site for "F6" drivers, then see [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/68505-sata-driver-load-windows-7-vista-setup.html) for details on how to select during Setup.

Comment: also look for 'textmode'.

Comment: The question is unclear whether there are partitions you can not see or that you can not create new partitions.